# Blocked sessions waiting with PAGELATCH_* wait types?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, optimization, locking, wait-types

Edited : Why are sessions reporting being blocked but waiting with `PAGELATCH_*`, and not `LCK_M_` related wait types?

I previously assumed that SQL server would only report blocking sessions in the blocking_session_Id column. If the blocked sessions were waiting for a logical lock and not anything else such as a `PAGELATCH_*`.

[image]

Comment: Looks like many concurrent sessions are inserting data into the table. Can you post the table structure along with indexes ?

Comment: @Kin the table begin inserted to by SPIDs  69, 82 and 84 does have a clustered index defined with a IDENTITY(1,1) property so it could be a case of last page insert contention but at this stage I'm more interested in why the blocked sessions are waiting with a non-locking related wait type. Also interestingly, SPID 93 is attempting to put an XLOCK on a totally unrelated table to the table being selected from by 64.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I previously assumed that SQL Server would only report a blocking session in the blocking_session_id column, if the blocked sessions were waiting for a logical lock and not anything else such as a `PAGELATCH_*`.

You are using Adam Machanic's `sp_WhoIsActive` procedure, not a built-in SQL Server facility. Adam's procedure reports all 'interesting' causes of blocking, not just lock blocking. The underlying information comes from various sources, including *sysprocesses*, *sys.dm_exec_requests*, and *sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks*.

A task can wait for other things besides a lock. It may be able, for example, to acquire an exclusive lock on a row on a page, but then still have to wait to acquire an exclusive page *latch* (because other tasks have latched the same page in an incompatible mode).

In your example, the `PAGELATCH_EX` exclusive page latches are on regular data or index pages, not PFS, GAM, SGAM, DCM, or BCM pages, as indicated by the (*) at the end of the *wait_info*.

You can find the documentation (blog entries) for `sp_WhoIsActive` [here](http://whoisactive.com).